# Is there a name for engines used in space vs those used in an atmosphere?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

Have engines been classified in this way? On Earth we have various engines (like steam) that are used, and there are rockets used to get us into space. Do these engines collectively fall under a named type of some kind, like "terrestrial engines?"

This would be as opposed to engines used in space, such as warp drive, impulse engines and the like from Star Trek (as an example). These would be "space engines."

But are there existing terms instead of these I made up to describe what I'm talking about?

Comment: Not a bad question but its not on topic.  You're not building something just asking for a definition.  Here is some good info for you.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propulsion

Comment: This might do better in http://english.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: go ahead and delete

Comment: The basic distinction is between thermal engines (or [heat engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine)) which convert heat into mechanical work, and electric engines (usually called [motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor)) which convert electrical energy into work. Heat engines are further subdivided by the source of heat, which can be chemical or atomic. (There could be also heat engines with electrically-produced heat but they are not used in practice electric motors are much more efficient.) Chemical heat engines can be air-breathing or rocket engines.

Comment: I was working on world building and trying to define engine types for my setting, so that's why this came us as a world building question.

Answer (score 2):

**Air Breathing propulsion (jets, piston engines) vs. Rockets**

In Aeronautical and Astronautical engineering, we speak of 'air breathing' propulsion systems, such as jet engines for airplanes.  Rockets (including ion engines and similar) bring all needed materials along with themselves.  I suppose you could also say 'non air-breathing' propulsion, if you wanted to; we call them rockets.

Comment: «along with» doesn’t scan.  Missing words?